# Alternative to secondary expansion in a makefile for GNU make 3.79.1

Tags: c++, makefile, design-patterns

I've been working on a makefile that uses secondary expansion not knowing that this feature only exists since version 3.81 of *GNU make*. Unfortunately, there are some old machines around here that only have make 3.79.1 installed and on these machines, the makefile doesn't work, of course. Is there an alternative to secondary expansion?

The rule for a C++ program where I use it looks like the following:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

# Pattern rule for linking
%_$(SYSTEM) : $$(%_ofiles) $(EXEC)/%_$(SYSTEM).o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

# Example for an ofiles variable
prog1_ofiles = $(C1) $(C2)

C1 = $(OFILES)/C1.o

C2 = $(OFILES)/C2.o
```

I know - the best solution would be to install a current make version. But our system administrator was not enthusiastic about it ;) So I'm looking forward to your suggestions.

Btw, does anyone know where to get the documentation of GNU make 3.79.1 - I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand how compiling a C++ program is no problem while compiling make is.  Install make in your home directory or something ...

Comment: I don't understand neither, but I'm not the admin. The makefile should be used for multiple users and on different systems. I can't expect everybody to maintain different versions of make.

Comment: The manual is here: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_toc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `make-3.81` sources in your source tree. Your main Makefile first should compile `make-3.81` using whatever make is available and then use `make-3.81` for compiling everything else.

Comment: Haha, simple and clever, I like this idea.

Answer (score 1):

What about a function/macro?  Using eval would achieve the same result as the secondary expansion. Certainly not as clean, but less typing than all the explicit rules.

```
define PROGRAM_template
$(1)_$(SYSTEM) : $$($(1)_ofiles) $(EXEC)/$(1)_$(SYSTEM).o
       $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
endef

$(foreach target, prog1 prog2 prog3, \
    $(eval $(call PROGRAM_template, $(target)))
```

Maybe you can wrap $$(%_ofiles) with eval in your original code and omit the foreach. Not sure...

Comment: `$(eval)` turned up in 3.80 AFAICR

Comment: At least it didn't exist in 3.79.1

Answer (score 1):

No `$(eval)`?, bah! You will have to write some shell to emit the specific make syntax into `file.mk` (say), and then `include` that into the Makefile. You bootstrap the process by telling make that the Makefile depends on `file.mk`. Make first has to update Makefile *before* anything else. So it will create `file.mk`, include it, and restart itself.

For your case it looks like `file.mk` will just contain dependencies and no recipes. A brief sketch:

```
%_${SYSTEM}: ${EXEC}/%_${SYSTEM}.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

file.mk:
    echo '%_${SYSTEM}: ${prog1_ofiles}' >$@

Makefile: file.mk

include file.mk
```

Comment: This only works for `prog1` and is the same as just adding `${prog1_ofiles}` to the prerequisites of the target `%_${SYSTEM}` - or did I miss something?

Comment: @Deve: Nope, you've got it. This is what I meant by "sketch." It's easy to see that it can be extended by replacing references to `prog1` with `${somemacro}`, and that the recipe for `file.mk` can be enhanced (such is life without `$(eval)`). It's also easy to see that it can be simplified as you suggested. All in all, a good bit of example code methinks.